# Rename output dll & lib file in openssl 3.0

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine, openssl-net

We are upgrading from openssl 1.0.2 to openssl 3.0.
Earlier we were able to rename the output dll by editing lib name in following files.

- util\mkdef.pl
- util\pl\VC-32.pl (pl folder does not exists in openssl 3.0, i guess it is changed to perl)
- ms\do_nasm.bat (did not exists in openssl3.0

Now there is no option to edit these files, I tried editing the filename in makefile & recompiled, but the output name did not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
It is achieved using configuration file, follow the solution in github.
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20439